# Rise time definition

Tags: circuit-design

I saw the following in a signals and systems book
[image]

[image]

They are defining rise time from 10% to 90% and hence the cut off frequency is based on that. However, from my knowledge of circuits - an RC circuit cutoff freq is 1/RC and the RC time constant is defined at 63%

Is rise time definition arbitrary?

Comment: no it's not arbitrary.. T10~90% = 0.35/f-3dB

Comment: https://www.electrical4u.com/rise-time/

Comment: But they then use that to define the cutoff freq. I am trying to compare these equations to an RC circuit where RC is time to 63%

Comment: I mean, if you look at the last equation, they define the cut off frequency as the inverse of the rise time. They define the rise time as time between 10% and 90%. Now, if you compare this to our RC circuit which has a cut off frequency of the inverse of the RC product. We know that the RC product is time taken to charge between 0% to 63%, not between 10% and 90%. Why is there an inconsistency ? - that’s my question.

Comment: You can define a rise time and then use it as per the definition. Normally it is 10% to 90%. Sometimes some manufacturers cheat a bit and say the rise time from 20% to 80% to make the time smaller, but when converted to 10% to 90% it is not so great. Some things are defined from 30% to 70%. For RC and 1st order stuff it takes 1 tau to charge from 0 to 63% and much longer to charge from 10% to 90% with same tau.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st order system  \$RC = T_{(0 ~to~ 63\text{%}~)}~~~\$  \$f_{-3dB}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}\$

2nd order system \$RC=2.2T_{\text{(10% to 90%})~~~}\$ based on (ln 0.90 - ln 0.10)=2.2, only if overdamped

This is equivalent to \$ f_{-3dB}= 0.35/T_\text{{0~90%}}~~\$  if overdamped.

In a second-order system, Tr is measured by;

- 0% to 100% for the underdamped system,
- 10% to 90% for the overdamped system, and 1st order also
- 5% to 95% for the critically damped system.

Thus if a DSO is rated for 1 ns rise time, it has a -3dB BW of 350 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

According to IEEE Std 181, the term *rise time* is deprecated. The preferred terminology is "transition duration", which is defined as

> The difference between the two reference level instants of the same
> transition. Unless otherwise specified, the two reference levels are
> the 10% and 90% reference levels.